# Get the value from a Kendo TimePickerFor helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have an mvc view with a kendo timepickerfor extension and I'm having an issue getting the value of this input using JQuery.  I've been looking on line for a solution and haven't seen one.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m.TimeIn)
                    .Format("hh:mm:ss tt")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { readOnly = "readOnly", id = "timeIn" })
                )
```

And the JQuery function looks like this:

```
var timeIn = $("#timeIn").data("kendoTimePicker").value();
```

Anyone know how to get the value of a "TimePickerFor" extension?

Thanks- Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/timepicker/api.html), it looks like your jQuery selector needs to hit the Name property of the TimePicker, which you aren't setting. Add a .Name("timeIn") to your call, and remove the id piece from your HtmlAttributes array. Disclaimer: I haven't done this, so it's totally untested.

Comment: Hello Harper, thanks for the reply. Not tested but it is correct :).  This is what I used:

Comment: I wish I would stop hitting Enter as if typing in Word.  I did not look in Telerik, thanks for the link!                                  var timeIn = $("#timeIn").val();